# For what value(s) of $a$ does the inequality $\prod_{i=0}^{a}(n-i) \geq a^{a+1}$ hold?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, closed-form, products

For what value(s) of $a$ does the inequality $\displaystyle \prod_{i=0}^{a}(n-i) \geq a^{a+1}$ hold? ($n,a \in \mathbb{N}, n > a$)

---

Supposedly for $a=\dfrac{n}{2}$:

$n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \dots (n-\frac{n}{2}) \geq \left( \dfrac{n}{2}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}+1}$

But I've not thought of a way to show this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $a-\frac{n}{2}$ you have
$$n \geq \frac{n}{2} \\
n-1 \geq \frac{n}{2}\\
....\\
n-\frac{n}{2} \geq \frac{n}{2}$$

Multiply them.

In general, the relation can only hold if there is a relation between $n$ and $a$.